# ssh permission denied please try again later - centos

Tags: centos, ssh

I have three servers, let's name them A, F and E. When I'm trying to ssh connect from server F to server E as root, the connection is established as expected and the other way around. Also when I'm connecting from F to A, it works the same way. But when I'm trying to connect from A to E, then I get the message ssh permission denied please try again later.

Comment: are you using public private key to authenticate? if yes then check E has A public key to allow ssh from it.

Comment: There is no public key,only password authentication

Comment: check the logs on E: `/var/log/secure`, and post lines pertaining to logins from A. If you find it does not provide enough information, up the log level by adjusting the `LogLevel` parameter in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `DEBUG` and reload the `sshd` service.

Answer (score 2):

Check the logs on the `E` system, They will almost certainly reside in `/var/log` and will equally likely contain information that is relevant to solving your problem. Once you have found log entries that are relevant if they are not immediately clear, you should just copy+paste them into your favourite search engine.